# MSTest.exe throws "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

Tags: mstest

On build server (Windows Server 2018 R2) I am using following command to execute tests:
MSTest.exe /testcontainer:artifacts\MyAssembly.Tests.dll /resultsfile:testresults-01.trx

This worked fine with .NET 4.7. Then I upgraded to .NET 4.7.2 and upgraded Visual Studio 2017 to version 15.8.3. After the upgrade the above command is failing.

Error from MSTest.exe logs:

W, 2476, 1, 2018/09/07, 09:23:42.270, VWBUILD02\MSTest.exe, TestType: #313, {ec4800e8-40e5-4ab3-8510-b8bf29b1904d}: Could not find string resource for name from 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.OrderedTest.Tip, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a:#313'

W, 2476, 1, 2018/09/07, 09:23:42.375, VWBUILD02\MSTest.exe, EqtException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I no longer use MSTest.exe on build server. I started using VSTest.Console.exe instead.